# How to make a div use 100% available height (minus top logo height)

Tags: css, html, height

I have this HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="logo">
    <table id="width100" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  >
        <tr>
            <td width="33.33%" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="33.34%" align="center"><a href="http://www.rawgameshop.com/"><img src="images/logo_new.png" /></a></td>
            <td width="33.33%" align="right"><img src="images/logo_right.png" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#731000" id="width100">
            <td height="15" colspan="3" ></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<center>
<div id="container">
    <div id="main_body">
        asd
    </div>
</div>
</center>
```

And this CSS:

```css
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#ECECEC;
}

#logo {
    width:100%;
    height:165px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;   
}

#width100 {
    width:100%;
}

#container {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    height:100%;
    width:900px;
}

#main_body {
    width:800px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    height:100%;
}
```

My question is: why doesn't my `main_body` div stretch down across the middle of the page? It is only as tall as the letters.

If I remove the `<center>` HTML tags it does stretch down, but at 100% screen size, that means I have to scroll down to the end. I wanted it to be to the edge of the screen, not further.

Comment: Your `#container` has `height:100%`, which _should_ occupy 100% screen height. If you don't mind using experimental features, try `calc()` CSS3 attribute; if you want to have wide-support, make `#logo` as `position:fixed` and add `padding-top:165px` to `body`.

Comment: I tried with padding and position, it doesn't work though, have a look here: http://rawgameshop.com/testindex.html

Comment: How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/LmxvV/4/ ?

Comment: Thanks, this is the easiest solution so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height:100%` takes the height of the first parent element that has a height set on it.  As all your parent objects have a percentage height on it will go right up to the body and take 100% of that height.

You will either need to set `#logo` as a percentage height and then your `main_body` as the rest of the percentage otherwise you will need javascript / jquery to resize your `main_body` as css hasn't enabled a way to do calculations yet (although I think it may be coming soon)

Have a look at this post as they were trying to achieve the same thing:

[Calculate value with CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309170/calculate-value-with-css3)

If you are going the jQuery route you will need to add the jquery library to your page (I usually put this at the bottom of the page) and then anywhere after this you need to include your script you are going to run like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () { 
    var newHeight = $(window).height() - $('#logo').height();
    var oldHeight = $('#container').height();

    if (newHeight > oldHeight) {
      $('#container').height(newHeight);
    }
  });
</script>
```

the `$(document).ready(function(){})` means that anything that is within the function will be fired once the document (web page) has finished loading

Comment: Is the javascript complicated? I worked a little with it and if it's not too difficult I could make it work. I never had any experience with jquery though.

Comment: javascript is pretty complicated, if you haven't worked with it I would use the jquery library as it makes working with javascript a lot easier

Comment: Any links you can give me that could help with that? I really want to make this work.

Comment: I'll make a demo on fiddle but you should look at jquery.com in the meantime

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to make it work by adjusting the height percentage of #logo and #container, it works neatly now.

Comment: I don't understand how the JS is linked to the html though, where is it initiated/used?

Comment: In some script tags you can use the function: 
    `$(document).ready(function () { //put your code here to run });`

Comment: I'm sorry but I sitll don't understand how to use it in this case, do you mind explaining?

Answer (score 0):

Add `height:100%` to `html,body` and remove `<center>` tag instead use `margin:0 auto` to `#container`

```
  html,body{height:100%}
  #container {
    background-color:red;
    height:100%;
    width:900px; margin:0 auto
  }
  #main_body {
    width:800px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    height:100%; margin:0 auto
  }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LmxvV/1/)**

---

For that issue change the html like this,

- Add an outer div to entire markup, make it `position:relative` and give `position:absolute` to container div
- use `z-index` to push the container div below the logo div.
- Finally add an empty div inside the `#main_body` to give the
  height(same as logo div height)

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="logo">
   logo html
</div>
<div id="container">    
    <div id="main_body">
        <div class="space"></div>
        asd
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
    height:100%; 
    background:grey; 
    position:relative; 
}
#container {
   background-color:red;  
   height:100%;
   width:900px; 
   margin:0 auto; 
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; 
   z-index:1;
}
#main_body {
   width:800px;  
   background-color:#FFFFFF;
   height:100%; 
   margin:0 auto; 
}
.space{height:165px}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/LmxvV/3/)**

Comment: Thank you! That worked, but I still have to scroll down to the end of the page, I guess it's those 165px from the top logo. How can I make it 100% of screen size and not 100% of screen height if you know what I mean?

Comment: @downvoter Show some concern to explain the reason for downvote

Comment: I did what you said, check out how it looks:

http://rawgameshop.com/

Not bad, but once you start scrolling down the main body goes over the logo, and I was hoping it would kind of "slide under", I basically wanted to have a static logo on top and then a body where only the content scrolls and the background is always the same. I hope that's not too complicated, is it?

Comment: @user2028762 so u need header to be fixed to the top (Even when you scroll the body)??