# iFrame 100% height minus header

Tags: css, html, iframe

I have an iframe with a height of 100% along with a div that sits above (height is 70px). The iframe overflows the page, but I want to be able to have the 100% height minus 70px so as that the scrollbar for the iframe fits into the page.

[image]

Comment: questions usually have a `?` in them.

Comment: you whant to know if its possible by css? if anyone know how to do using js? what?

Comment: Try making a div with a fixed size and insert the iFrame in there.

Comment: Can you use a lower percentage value? I guess this post probably can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624374/how-to-make-a-div-use-100-available-height-minus-top-logo-height?rq=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. I just added a parent div around the iframe.

```
<div class="parent">
    <iframe src="http://reddit.com"> </iframe>
</div>
```

```
.parent{
    margin-top: 70px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px; 
    bottom: 0px;
}

iframe{
    position:absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I wonder why the extra `DIV` is needed, but this works for me.

Comment: Dumb that this was closed as "not a real question" because it doesn't have a "?" at the end. Was trying to do the exact same thing and this helped me, thanks.

Comment: Helped me too just now, great answer. Voted to re-open the question (even though it's fairly old, it's still relevant

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting a height on the iframe, use absolute positioning so that its top is 70px from the edge of the page while the other sides are 0px away.